# How to reach local sites in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

If I try to get onto my local media server in chrome, which has an address such as ' openelec ' or '12.234.12.5' it will just google whatever I type in to the address/search bar. How can I temporarily avoid this normally helpful feature to access these services in chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `http://` before the address.

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler than typing http:// before the address, you can usually type / after it:

```
openelec/
12.234.12.5/
```